# SQL Selecting All columns based on max value of two column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
PkReferencesID    FkReferencesID   DocID    FKHRSEmployeeID  AssignedDate  AssignedTime  FKActivityID
40855             NULL             8530     13               13920625      0829          1
40856             40855            8530     438              13920625      0829          1
40857             40856            8530     13               13920625      0829          2
40858             40857            8530     438              13920625      0830          1
40859             40858            8530     NULL             13920625      0830          1
NULL              NULL             NULL     NULL             NULL          NULL          NULL
```

How i can select rows with DocID = 8530 and FKActivityID = 1 and Maximum AssignedDate and Maximum AssignedTime for per FKHRSEmployeeID?

Note:the result should be one row for per FKHRSEmployeeID

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

The result must be like this

### PkReferencesID    FkReferencesID   DocID    FKHRSEmployeeID  AssignedDate  AssignedTime  FKActivityID

40855             NULL       8530            13    13920625      0829            1
40858             40857          8530           438    13920625      0830            1

Comment: What result set are you expecting to get from your sample table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by FKHRSEmployeeID
                                order by AssignedDate desc, AssignedTime desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      where DocID = 8530 and FKActivityID = 1 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Query 2 will retrieve the information you're asking for:

Query1: This query gets the maximum assigned date/time for each employee.

```
SELECT FKHRSEmployeeID, MAX(AssignedDate & AssignedTime)
FROM Table
WHERE T.DocID=8530 
  AND T.FKActivityID=1
GROUP BY FKHRSEmployeeID;
```

Query2: This query uses the former one to retrieve only the matching records.

```
SELECT T.*
FROM Table AS T 
  INNER JOIN Query1 AS Q 
    ON (T.Date=LEFT(Q.MaxDateTime,8)) 
    AND (T.Time=RIGHT(Q.MaxDateTime,4)) 
    AND (T.FKHRSEmployeeID=Q.FKHRSEmployeeID)
WHERE T.DocID=8530 
  AND T.FKActivityID=1;
```

This query by itself doesn't guarantee you'll only get one record per employee, unless the combination FKHRSEmployeeID/AssignedDate/AssignedTime is unique in the table. You can ensure this by creating a unique index based on those columns.